# Convert encodings to raw characters using R language

Tags: r, character-encoding

I have encoded characters such as `"\032\032\032\032\032\032\032\032"` and I want to convert them to raw characters in `R`. How can this be done?

Comment: Did you try `charToRaw()`?

Comment: I tried but it is not working

Comment: So this: `charToRaw("\032\032\032\032\032\032\032\032")
[1] 1a 1a 1a 1a 1a 1a 1a 1a` is not what you expect to get?

Comment: This is not i am expecting.I would like to have some text may be non english for representing the "\032\032\032\032\032\032\032\032"

Comment: code formatting, adding tag